# can not resolve method get(int)

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

After getting response from server i am storing points in my integer array and i am trying to add that array in my horizontal scrollview,but it gives me error in my loop,following is my code can anyone help?thanks advance

Error near this line

```
tv.setText(points.get(i));
```

JAVA

```
 protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... args) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(PLACE_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                   placejsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    // state_list = jsonObj.getJSONArray(COUNTRY_LIST);
                    // looping through All Contacts

                        jobject = placejsonObj.getJSONObject(0);
                        msgs=jobject.getString("user_status");

                        pointsarray=placejsonObj.getJSONArray(1);
                       // points=pointsarray.getString("point");
                    System.out.println("Kya yar" + "Failure"+pointsarray);
                    points = new int[pointsarray.length()];
                    for(int m=0; m<pointsarray.length(); m++) {
                        points[m] = pointsarray.getJSONObject(m).getInt("point");
                    }
                    System.out.println("array contains" + points.length + " elements");


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
            return null;
        }


protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();




         for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            tv = new TextView(getActivity());
            tv.setText(points[i]+",");
           tv.setTag(points[i]);
            yourLayout.addView(tv);
        }

        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int point = (int) view.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),point,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**points** is an `array` so do like

```
tv.setText(""+points[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

To get item from `Array` Use `points[i]` and to get item from `List` use `points.get(i)`;

Comment: dhaval can you tell how to get selected points on textview click listener?

Comment: @Jolly you can use TextView's setTag and getTag method for that. tv.setTag(points.get(i)); and in onClick method, use int point  = (int) view.getTag()

Comment: i set this way tv.setTag(points[i]);..but in my tv.setonclick not able to get

Comment: Have your tried **int point = (int) view.getTag();** in onClick method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95337/discussion-between-jolly-and-dhaval-patel).

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems as I see. The first is you try to set the text using an int, and the second is the way you try to access the data in the array (you use it like a list). Try it like this:

```
tv.setText(points[i] + "");
```

Comment: Edited the dot out, Thanks @MD